# Как подвинуть лого в центр страницы вместо поиска

Tags: html, css

Добрый день, хотел у вас спросить как все таки поставить лого по центру сайта.
Вместо поиска поставить лого, а сам поиск поставить в верхнюю часть где социальные кнопки.Честно признаю пишу только после того как сам сломаю голову, пока точно пойму что я не сделаю в связи с нехваткой знаний. [Сайт](http://masterskaya55.ru)

Вот див лого

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 logo-inner">
  <div class="logo-store">
    <a href="http://masterskaya55.ru/index.php?route=common/home">
      <img src="http://masterskaya55.ru/image/catalog/logo5.png"
           title="Мастерская 55 - обувная мастерская" alt="Мастерская 55 - обувная мастерская">
    </a>
</div>
```

А вот CSS стиля

```
.logo-inner {
position: relative;
z-index: 99;
```

Хотел вообще получить в итоге вот так как на картинке 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

У вас там есть элемент `<div class="row">`. В нём внутри элементы с классами `col-xx-y`. В первом лежит логотип. Во втором -- поиск. Просто переставив их местами можно получить то, чего вы хотите.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем можно заниматься подгонкой ширины колонок, изменяя `y` в `col-xx-y`

Подробнее о том, как работает концепция Grid, можно почитать [тут](http://bootstrap-3.ru/css.php#grid).

При хорошем раскладе в стили вообще не придётся лезть. На то CSS-фреймворки и созданы, чтобы как можно сильнее автоматизировать процесс вёрстки.

> Как выровнять сетку?

За "выравнивание" сетки отвечает `col-xx-offset-y`, который позволяет смещать элементы от левого края на заданное число колонок.

Практический пример:

**html**

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12 col-sm-offset-4 logo-inner">
  <div class="logo-store">
    <a href="http://masterskaya55.ru/index.php?route=common/home">
      <img src="http://masterskaya55.ru/image/catalog/logo5.png" title="Мастерская 55 - обувная мастерская" alt="Мастерская 55 - обувная мастерская">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание, что я удалил класс `.hidden-xs` и теперь элемент не будет скрыт в мобильной версии.

**CSS**

```
.logo-inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

P.S.: спасибо медведю гризли за CSS

Comment: Спасибо за решение, но не подскажите почему в мобильной версии он пропадает вообще ?

Comment: @PashaDark Доступ к сайту в данный момент закрыт и я не могу проверить этого наверняка, но подозреваю, что там присутствует класс `.hidden-xs` http://bootstrap-3.ru/css.php#responsive-utilities

Comment: Открыл сайт, еще вопрос как все такие выровнять сетку )

Comment: @PashaDark можно поконкретнее, что вы имеете в виду под "выровнять"?

Comment: Посмотрите сайт) вы поймете )

Comment: Нет все таки не как не могу понять как сделать это.Может не там.

Answer (score 1):

Пожалуйста :-)

```css
.logo-inner {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 logo-inner">
  <div class="logo-store">
    <a href="http://masterskaya55.ru/index.php?route=common/home">
      <img src="http://masterskaya55.ru/image/catalog/logo5.png" title="Мастерская 55 - обувная мастерская" alt="Мастерская 55 - обувная мастерская">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```